# Starting my application when windows starts up (All versions of Windows)?

Tags: windows, delphi, registry, delphi-2010

I am writing an application using Delphi 2010. I would like to have my application start up when windows starts up. I need this to work in the latest versions of Windows XP, 7.0, and the latest servers.

Would storing it under the following key work, or do i need to do something else?

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

thanks for any help

Comment: sorry, i should not that when attempting to do this with inno setup, i get an access denied when i run my setup

Comment: There is no "Windows 7.0". The version number of "Windows 7" is 6.1.

Comment: shell startup is much more user friendly

Comment: @user205376 by shell startup do you mean the Startup folders in the Windows start menu? If so then I agree that that is a more user-friendly and visible approach.

Comment: Using Inno Setup, here is my registry script line: Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "Alerts.exe"; ValueData: "{app}\Alerts.exe" - if i comment this out, the program installs and runs file, but of course, i am missing the registry entry. If i uncomment it and install the program, i get a Access Denied error message, but the registry entry is created as well. Is there something wrong with my inno setup script registry line? Maybe this is a question for a inno setup forum <smile>

Comment: @David Heffernan it has been there even before Start Menu and "Folder" term :-)

Comment: @user205376 Do tell more about *shell startup* - it's still not obvious to me exactly what this is. How about a URL to a pertinent MSDN topic?

Comment: Define "all versions of windows": you want to have this working in 16-bit Windows 1.0?

Comment: It should be startup my app when the user logs on. Because the only way to make your app start when windows start (boot) is to make it a service or a driver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That will only result in it starting when the user running the installation process connects. If you want it to start when Windows starts then try under HKLM.

Comment: While run entries under HKLM will start before ones under HKCU, they both will run after logon: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179365

Comment: I dont believe HKLM is allowed under the new XP and Win 7 security is it?

Comment: Im not sure, im just asking. Can a program create a new registry key in HKLM without and admin rights, etc.

Comment: @Shane No you cannot write to HKLM without admin privileges, but you generally install software with elevated privileges. If you want something to start every time Windows runs then you are going to need elevated privileges.

Comment: Sorry, i believe this is a question / answer related to inno setup. My bad

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that these Run key entries execute when a user logs on. To launch a task on startup, it's better to write windows services, which is quite easy to do in Delphi.

A little help on services: http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/delphi-windows-service-applications.htm

Comment: Your statements are all correct, but if the OP wants an app with a GUI then that rules out a service.

Comment: Not if the service runs the core logic of the app, and the GUI is used only to display status and invoke actions within the service.  In that scenerio, a bootup service and an after-login app can be used together.

Comment: Nothing was ever said about GUI either way